# Trying to populate a SELECT menu with Javascript/jQuery, but script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a page where selecting the Department will populate a < SELECT > (named #SEL_Position) with the various < OPTION > tags it should have within it listing the positions that fall under that department only. [I found a script to go from](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically) that does exactly what I'm looking for (the way I previously had it working didn't work in IE) and attempted to implement it. Selecting an item from the #SEL_Department makes the #SEL_Position appear, which I already had working. However, the script to populate the positions— which worked where I found it— doesn't seem to affect the HTML within #SEL_Position, leaving it entirely blank.

So you can see what I've got, `enter code here`[here's a JSFiddle of the page.](http://jsfiddle.net/ManiacClown/8w387zzy/) What am I doing wrong? Did I miss something? Did I make some stupid typo I can't see because my brain's filling in what I "know" I did? I'd like to get this script working because it looks like it'll be easy to maintain in the future.

Comment: All right, I've gotten it sort of working by placing the script entirely inside the page instead of in an external Javascript file. However, there are still two problems.

1) For some reason the suggestion from @JosephMarikle to use .trigger('change') leads to an overflow of the call stack. It works for him on JSFiddle but not on the live server on my side.

2) On the live page, Whatever the first selection is, the Position menu appears but is blank, apparently for lack of `case_var`. You have to select a Department other than what you want and THEN select your Department and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of typoes:

- `$(this).attr("case_var")` should be `$('option:selected', this).attr("case_var")`
- `list(DeptExecutive);` should be `list(Dept_Executive);`
- `$("#SEL_Position").append("option...` should be `$("#SEL_Position").append("<option...`

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/dk0pjhw4/

Comment: O.K., that's weird. It works on JSFiddle but it doesn't work on our server. I even copy/pasted your script into a new .js file and referenced that one and it still didn't work on our server.

Comment: @NickZachariasen Make sure you're paying attention to the error output of the console.  All I did for this demo was throw in a few `console.log` calls to debug and noted what came up as errors in the javascript console.  My guess is that some path is wrong or jquery isn't leaded yet or some other trical reason that it's breaking.

Comment: Would it matter that this is an ASPX file using a master page layout? I've made sure the links are correct in the master page and commented out the jQuery loading in the individual file.

In either case, it turned out that to clear out the console errors it was giving me about jQuery loading (which apparently didn't entirely prevent it from working) stemmed from Visual Studio demanding I browse for the location of the jQuery files instead of hand-coding them. I no longer have any errors show in Chrome's console on load. How can I check where else this is going awry?

Comment: First, you should make sure the script is being reached.  Errors in javascript tend to prevent further javascript from executing.  You can check by throwing in a few logging calls. Try placing one before `var Dept_Executive = [` to make sure it's actually getting to that part.  A simple `console.log('starting execution')` will work. Then see if that phrase gets logged when you run the page. You can incrementally add this call further and further down the script until you find where it's not executing.  Then if you're sure it's getting to the script try `console.log(department)` in `.change()`.

Comment: This is basically poor mans' breakpoints.  You can utilize your browser too, adding breakpoints in the script itself (using developer tools).  developer tools can be more powerful, but they also take time to learn (not a bad idea to do for future debugging).  `console.log` works and is pretty easy to add if you just need to test something quick.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out how to use console.log(). It looks like it is indeed failing on the change(), which gives me an idea. Do you think it could be that I have two separate scripts listening for a change() in #SEL_Department? I have the one that hides the placeholder text and makes the menu visible (starting at line 116 in your Fiddle's version), then I've got the one in the separate script.

I wonder if it isn't a conflict between the two as to what to do on the change() event. If so, I'd think I should put the show() part in this script instead of in the base page.

Comment: event listeners work a little differently than that.  You can have both in two separate files and they'll work simultaneously.  Event listeners work by "adding" them to the event trigger.  When 'change' is triggered, both listeners will fire.  The order in which they will be fired depends on the order in which they were added.  You can have any number of event listeners attached to the same event.

Comment: O.K., that's strange. Putting the script directly into the page works except for some reason to make Executive work you have to select something else and then select it. Thanks for all the assistance! This was (and still is) really bizarre.

Comment: Glad I could help.  It could be that it's not selecting it because you have a disabled option selected by default.  When I open the dropdown, it says it has Executive selected, but I know based on the code that "Select Department" (which does not appear in the dropdown) is the actual current selection.  If you want "Executive" to be selected by default, you can just remove that first, disabled option.  Then if you want it to populate the list on page load, just add `.trigger('change')` to it.  Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/dk0pjhw4/1/